# apex visualforce code review

Tags: apex, visualforce, code

Are there any tools which can be used freely to review apex and visualforce code written and provide some suggestions about code improvement and applying best practices. I need to check quality of apex and visualforce code written and improve the same.

Comment: I've been mulling about creating an app that does that, because the Force.com Scanner tool is only concerned with security violations, not actual "best practices". Something like a Apex Lint tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the checkmarx based force.com scanner: http://security.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scanner

Have a read of the faq stuff first and I think it's really aimed at partner/appexchange apps but it's useful. It's not meant to be used often (I.e. Part of an organisations development cycle) but the site does explain that.

Answer (score 2):

There are not many options for static code analyzer like we have in Java.  
However you can  try the Apex PMD plugin for eclipse. Available at http://codescan.villagechief.com/eclipse/  
 Github, Jenkins facilitate the code review at peer level but does not provide any analysis on its own like PMD, FindBugs